# Firing events from dynamically added html

Tags: angular, release, final

i have to load Html data from server like i have 'click'

but when i assign this data to innerHtml property in angular2 it shows html but click even is not working .

is there any solution for this problem.

there are some suggestions to use dynamic Components but i don't find any good tutorial for final angular2 release.

```
import { Component,  ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpComponent}  from './http.component';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="myVal"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {


myVal: string = '<div><button onClick="showdata()"> Show Data </button></div>';

constructor(){}

    showdata(){
        console.log("test");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a click handler this way, it won't refer to the `showdata()` in Angulars component but for `window.showdata()`. Angular doesn't know about `onclick` and `onclick` doesn't know about Angular.

I would suggest you add the HTML to the component, then query for the element and add an event handler using

```ts
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('button').addEventHandler('click', this.showdata.bind(this);
}
```

While `ngAfterViewInit()` might not be the right place for the code, depending on when the HTML is added.

Comment: But this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('button') will not select the dynamically added button

Comment: Sure it will. You need to ensure the button was actually added before you query.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to use JavaScript to listen the click event and get the element by id:

component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var myVal = document.getElementById("myVal");
    myVal.innerHTML = '<div><button id="btn"> Show Data </button></div>'; 
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("Button clicked, do something.");
});
}
```

template:

```
<div id="myVal"></div>
```

Its working for me.

Comment: Can I call a function in the component inside this function?