# Angular 2: Use (click) to invoke function in service

Tags: angular

I want to invoke a function from a service that I created when you click on something, but I can't get it to work. I simplified it as much as possible just to see if this type of functionality is even possible.

I have the following HTML:

```
<a (click)="SellingVarietiesService.goToVarietyDetails(3)">Test</a>
```

Here is the code for the function I want to invoke:

```
@Injectable()
export class SellingVarietiesService {    

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public goToVarietyDetails(varietyId: any): void {        
        console.log(varietyId);
    }
}
```

The HTML is being generated via .NET/C# and returned from an HTTP call in a service I created. Is it possible to invoke that function in my service with the HTML that is being returned to me? Do I just have the syntax wrong?

EDIT:

I used DomSanitizer on the HTML that I returned (the HTML that contains the (click) function). Here is the code from my component that used it:

```
// Get Variety List
getVarietyList() {        
    this.sellingMenuService.getVarieties().subscribe(res => {            
        this.varietyListSelling = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
    });
}
```

And here is the HTML where that gets placed:

```
<div *ngIf="varietyListSelling" [innerHtml]="varietyListSelling"></div>
```

Here is an example of the what `res` might look like:

```
<div class="varietyName">
    <a class="" (click)="sellingVarietiesService.goToVarietyDetails(1176)" >Starbor</a>
    <a href="#deleteVarietySelling" id="deleteVarietySelling_1176" class="quick-delete fa-minus-button" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How does `res` looks like?

Comment: I added to the end of my post. Notice (click)="sellingVarietiesService.goToVarietyDetails(1176) is there, yet doesn't work.

Comment: It won't work because it should be compiled at first

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063791/firing-events-from-dynamically-added-html or use dynamic component loading like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2

Comment: I tried the first one and changed my code to this: this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('a.testClick').addEventHandler('click', this.getVarietyDetails.bind(this));

It gave me this error:
Cannot read property 'addEventHandler' of null

Comment: i add "testClick" class to the anchor tags with the (click) functions

Comment: If I were to return JSON data instead of HTML and format it with Angular 2, would that solve my problem? Or would I still need to use dynamic component loading?

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject service into component that hosts your html

```
@Component({
  template: `<a (click)="svs.goToVarietyDetails(3)">Test</a>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor( public svs: SellingVarietiesService) {}
}
```

Then you can access it through component property.

Comment: Yup, I did that, but it still isn't working. I'm wondering if it is because the HTML is served up from my .NET backend. I don't know if that would cause issues but I can't think of any other reason...

Comment: If that's the case look into [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html)

Comment: I updated my post to show how I used DomSanitizer. Is there a different way I need to be using it?

Comment: Property is `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml` (:

Comment: AFAIK the `innerHtml` property works like standart property `innerHTML`